# Super in prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what the right way to handle a "super" object in prototypal inheritance (as described by Douglas Crockford) should be. Currently I am using `this.__proto__`, which leads to weird behavior when creating new objects. Here is a simple example.

```
var Animal = { talk: function() { return "I am an animal"}}
var Cat = Object.create(Animal);                            
Cat.talk = function(){return "I am a cat. " + this.__proto__.talk()}; 
var myCat = Object.create(Cat)
console.log(myCat.talk());
```

What I want the final output to be is "I am a cat. I am an animal." Instead what I get is "I am a cat. I am a cat. I am an animal.". This makes perfect sense since the prototype of myCat is Cat, not animal!

How do I deal with this behavior to replicate the inheritance from other languages that I know and love?

**Update 1/5/2015**
I gave up on prototypal inheritance. One of these days I'll just switch to typescript I think...

Comment: Give it up. Don't try to shoehorn prototype-based inheritance into a class-based inheritance paradigm.

Comment: @MattBall What is the fundamental difference?

Comment: Overriding methods isn't something I'd personally do in classical or prototypal inheritance in this scenario anyways.  `Cat.meow` for instance.

Comment: Why are you using `__proto__` instead of just calling a method from known object? If you try to mimick statically typed languages, the inheritance relation is static and known in compile time there too.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments! I agree with @Jamen that overriding feels futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need explicitly mention **Animal** as **Cat**'s parent

```
var Animal = { talk: function() { return "I am an animal"}}
var Cat = Object.create(Animal);           
Cat.parent = Animal;    //so that you can invoke its method later
Cat.talk = function(){return "I am a cat. " + this.parent.talk.call(this)}; 
var myCat = Object.create(Cat);
```

Other than this I don't see how you will do this without specifically referring `Animal` class while defining `Cat.talk`.

Comment: Note that `this` inside the parent will refer to `Animal` (doesn't matter in the example but could be unexpected later) unless you call it like `this.parent.talk.call( this );`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should call the Animal's talk function, but pass your cat in for the `thisArg`:

```
Animal.talk.call( this );
```

All together:

```
var Animal = { talk: function() { return "I am an animal"}}
var Cat = Object.create(Animal);                            
Cat.talk = function(){return "I am a cat. " + Animal.talk.call( this )}; 
var myCat = Object.create(Cat)
console.log(myCat.talk());
```

Comment: I was missing the "call" method. Thanks!